# Share internet connection from laptop to laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, internet-connection

Is it possible to share my internet connection from my laptop to my friends laptop?

Comment: Can the laptops be hard-wired together, or does this need to be a wireless connection (or doesn't it matter)?  What kind of distance and location considerations are you dealing with?  How is your laptop connected to the Internet?  Are you concerned with bandwidth limitations on either laptop?  Does the bandwidth of your connection support both of your requirements?

Comment: It's a wired connection, i'm just wondering if there's an way.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your laptop's wireless adapter to serve as an access point. I am not sure though if that disables your own usage, I'd think not, but I did not try:

[image]

You might want to uncheck the lower check box.

Comment: can i do this with a wired connection?

Comment: I think so, I just opened my wireless adapter's properties for the screen copy. The wired connection should show the same option. However, how do you want to connect the two machines? you would need a second connection, either a second LAN or a wireless connection.

Comment: how do i setup a second lan?

Comment: You need a second cable and a second adapter. That is very rare to have, so I doubt your machine has it. How did you imagine to connect the two computers?? Typically, people use wireless, but if you have no wireless, how do you mechanically want to connect them??

Comment: share connection via usb, one computer has internet and share it with the other.